# How to create a local repository and remote repository in Gitlab using command line?

Tags: git, gitlab

I have created one project. I want to store my project in Gitlab. How to create a local repository and remote repository in Gitlab using command line?
I am looking for creating both local repository and remote repository creation.

I got the solution.
Steps to create Local repository and remote repository using Gitlab.

1. `git init`(Local repository created)
2. `git add .`
3. `git commit -m "message"`
4. Git push using SSH(Remote repository created):

`git push --set-upstream git@gitlab.example.com:your-username/nonexistent-project.git master`

Git push using HTTP:

```
git push --set-upstream https://gitlab.example.com/your-username/nonexistent-project.git master
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33101962/how-to-create-a-new-gitlab-repo-from-my-existing-local-git-repo-using-cli/42311714 this might help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a new gitlab repo from my existing local git repo, using CLI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33101962/how-to-create-a-new-gitlab-repo-from-my-existing-local-git-repo-using-cli)

Comment: @PraveenP I was looking for creating both local repository and remote repository. The above question only answers about creating remote repository. So this is not a duplicate and also I got the solution for my question and mentioned in my question also.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Steps to create Local repository and remote repository using Gitlab.

1. `git init`(Local repository created)
2. `git add .`
3. `git commit -m "message"`
4. Git push using SSH(Remote repository created):

   ```
   git push --set-upstream git@gitlab.example.com:namespace/nonexistent-project.git master
   ```

   Git push using HTTP:

   ```
   git push --set-upstream https://gitlab.example.com/namespace/nonexistent-project.git master
   ```