# How to create git remote repository command line?

Tags: git, command-line

I know that method, to first init an empty repo and then adding remote origin
using command
`git remote add origin https://github.com/USER/TEST_REPO.git`

for this, we first need to create remote repo at github.com manually, and then pass this url (https://github../TEST_REPO.git) into git remote add command.

I am just finding a way to create that remote repository using command, instead of manually creating from github.com.

I try to find this method at git official docs, from google, already questions asked at stackoverflow and quora etc. But I didn't find any relevant answer.

[From existing Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51811227/how-to-create-a-local-repository-and-remote-repository-in-gitlab-using-command-l)

From Above link, I tried command with my username and desired repo name; but It says, 'Repository not found'

```
git push --set-upstream https://gitlab.example.com/your-username/nonexistent-project.git master
```

Any kind of help will be appreciated,

Comment: See https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_create.

Comment: This isn't something Git alone can do. For GitHub explicitly, you'll need to use the API they provide.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the git hosting service that you use. Most will offer an API to do this.

For example, github has [a REST API that can be used to create new repositories](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/repos?apiVersion=2022-11-28#create-an-organization-repository). Example from their documentation that uses [the GitHub CLI](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_api):

```
gh api \
  --method POST \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  /orgs/ORG/repos \
  -f name='Hello-World' \
 -f description='This is your first repository' \
 -f homepage='https://github.com' \
 -F private=false \
 -F has_issues=true \
 -F has_projects=true \
 -F has_wiki=true
```