# Best way to create a GitLab Repository from a local project

Tags: eclipse, git, gitlab, repository, git-bash

Whats the most easiest way to create a repository for my local Java Eclipse Projects?
Currently I create a Repo on GitLab an clone it. Then i move the .git folder to the new Empty Eclipse Project. then add, commit and push all. Its so annoying.

Isnt there an easier way to do this?

I've already searched for it, but i can't find anything out about an easier way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a new gitlab repo from my existing local git repo, using CLI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33101962/how-to-create-a-new-gitlab-repo-from-my-existing-local-git-repo-using-cli)

Comment: Maybe this as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20359936/import-an-existing-git-project-into-gitlab

Comment: @LeGEC looks good, but it just show me this:

`error: src refspec master does not match any´

Comment: @Jan : do you have a local branch named `master` ? replace `master` with the name of the branch you want to push ; as said in the post, repeat this for each branch you wish to push to the remote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just try below command in your root project

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m 'your commit'
git remote add origin <git url> // <git url>: git@mygitLab.com:test.git
git push -u -f origin master
```